# Using Except() to compare two Lists made of custom objects not returning expected result

Tags: c#, list

I am trying to compare two lists of objects of same custom type (CompareClass).

```
var firstfromsec = Excel.CADlist.Except(Excel.SKMlist).ToList();
var secfromfirst = Excel.SKMlist.Except(Excel.CADlist).ToList();
```

Both Excel.CADlist and Excel.SKMlist are static CompareClass lists.

Here is first line from the result of both lists:

> firstfromsec:  V00000700000 001 5x6 mm2 GDP400-01 ...
>
> secfromfirst: V00000700000 001 5x6 mm2 GDP400-01 ...

I am using Except() for the first time, but I dont understand why am I getting
exact same objects instead of differences between lists ?

Comment: `Except` will use `GetHashCode` and `Equals` on the objects to determine equality.  If the class in those collections do not override those methods then it will do reference equality and not value equality.  Meaning two objects with the same values will not be viewed as equal.

Comment: I understand, thanks. Can You tell me which way I should go to achieve what I have tried. I would like that these objects are viewed as same

Comment: You have two options.  You can override the `Equals` and `GetHashCode` methods of the class, or you can use the overload of `Except` that takes a `IEqualityComparer<T>` where you can tell it how to compare the objects.

Comment: The trick is to either override `GetHashCode()` and `Equals` methods of the `CompareClass` class to work as required, or to implement your own `IEqualityCompare<CompareClass>` and to pass an instance of that to `Except`.

Comment: Can you share `CompareClass` source code?

Comment: Pavel Its just a small class having 4 string properties,nothing else. I made It just to compare two documents, from which I created 2 lists of CompareClass objects.

Comment: You could use value tuples (or the `Tuple` class) instead which will automatically have the value equality you are looking for.  Or even anonymous classes if the objects don't need to be passed out of a method.

Comment: juharr can You provide answer using Tuple class? I will try It also, but maybe some pointers would be helpful, and also for other people in the future.

Comment: I'd have to see the code where you create the collections you are comparing to really show how to switch to using tuples.

Comment: Overriding `Equals` and `GetHashCode` in the `CompareClass` will solve the problem here, and will provide a good learning opportunity (and is very easy to do). If you post the class definition, someone will help, or just do a quick research here and try it yourself! Then come back if you get stuck.

Comment: Ok Thanks everyone, I am trying myself, given the pointers from you